# Import Access table into Excel table without first record being Access field labels

Tags: excel, ms-access

This is probably simple but I have been having trouble figuring this out.

I have a MS Excel spreadsheet tool built and I want to import the data from an MS Access table. I got the link to work just fine but the first imported record is the Access field names. Is there a way to skip that and make the first record in Excel the first actual Access record?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a named table linked to the data you can just uncheck "Header row" from the table design tab:

[image]